# Upvotes don't update

Tags: support

I'm sure this is a duplicate question, but I can't find anything, so I'm sorry.

Recent upvotes I got didn't update for nearly an hour now (although they're not very much), and my rep stays the same. Is this a bug? Or the site refreshes with some intervals?

If this is a duplicate question, please give me the links, so I can find my answer.

Comment: Blame the cache.

Comment: Okay then. I'll delete this stupid question.

Comment: @purplehuman thats not a stupid question, thats why this blog was made for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My rep updates basically instantly. Looking at your [profile reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4516901/purplehuman?tab=reputation), the last reputation change you had was 6 hours ago:

[image]

Maybe someone upvoted your post then removed the upvote, so you think you gained 10 rep.

Comment: Since then I got new upvotes. For example this comment of mine got 2 upvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325195/gitignore-a-file-if-file-with-different-extension-exists#comment45004638_28325195

Comment: Comments don't affect your reputation.

Comment: Ah, okay then. I'm sorry. So, it IS a stupid question.